# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '–' (T_STRING) in PHP

Tags: syntax-error, subtraction, parse-error

I am getting a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '–' (T_STRING) in the following line:

```
$lbm = ((0.407 * $weightkg) + (0.267  * $heightcm) - 19.2) / 0.453592;
```

From what I see, I am using a subtraction sign and not a hyphen. Other than that, I don't know what could be wrong. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try: Delete the - and type in a - from the keyboard. The error does not look related to that code. Have a test case snippet link from an online REPL?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the character you pasted into the title is *definitely* an en-dash rather than a minus symbol<sup>(a)</sup> so PHP is rightly complaining about it.

The line in the main body of your question *is* a hyphen so either you've typed in in differently or that's not the line where the error is (PHP can sometimes be a bit iffy as to where it reports errors, so you may want to look on the few lines immediately *around* the one it reports the error to be on).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Which is actually *distinct* from a hyphen, at least in typography, so you may want to beware of lunatic typographers coming around to beat you up for your transgressions :-)